# Is there a tool or script to parse XML file and copy paste nested elements

Tags: python, xml, bash, shell, xslt

I have two XML files say - old.xml and new.xml

old.xml:

```
<GROUPS>
<GROUP>
<ID>1</ID>
<RESULT>123</RESULT>
</GROUP>
<GROUP>
<ID>2</ID>
<RESULT>999</RESULT>
</GROUP>
</GROUPS>
```

new.xml:

```
<GROUPS>
<GROUP>
<ID>2</ID>
<RESULT>015</RESULT>
</GROUP>
<GROUP>
<ID>4</ID>
<RESULT>631</RESULT>
</GROUP>
</GROUPS>
```

Now my aim is to parse through each GROUP of old.xml and if any group with similar ID which is present in new.xml, then copy and paste its result from old.xml to new.xml.

For example, in the above sample files, we have ID=2 in both .xml, I want to copy 999 tag of new.xml where GROUP ID=2.

Required output:

```
<GROUPS>
<GROUP>
<ID>2</ID>
<RESULT>999</RESULT>
</GROUP>
<GROUP>
<ID>4</ID>
<RESULT>631</RESULT>
</GROUP>
</GROUPS>
```

Is there some easy tool for XMLs which can do these kind of things or do I need to create a script? or if this is possible through XSL? I am not sure. Please guide.

Comment: Are you sure `<ID=1>` is specified this way? This isn't valid XML.

Comment: @AndrejKesely Yes sorry about that. I've fixed that in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution using Python and `BeautifulSoup` module:

```
xml1 = '''<GROUPS>
<GROUP>
<ID>1</ID>
<RESULT>123</RESULT>
</GROUP>
<GROUP>
<ID>2</ID>
<RESULT>999</RESULT>
</GROUP>
</GROUPS>'''

xml2 = '''<GROUPS>
<GROUP>
<ID>2</ID>
<RESULT>015</RESULT>
</GROUP>
<GROUP>
<ID>4</ID>
<RESULT>631</RESULT>
</GROUP>
</GROUPS>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup1 = BeautifulSoup(xml1, 'xml')
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(xml2, 'xml')

groups_2 = {g.ID.get_text(strip=True): g for g in soup2.select('GROUP:has(> ID)')}

for g in soup1.select('GROUP:has(> ID)'):
    i = g.ID.get_text(strip=True)
    if i in groups_2:
        groups_2[i].replace_with(g)

print(soup2)
```

Prints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GROUPS>
<GROUP>
<ID>2</ID>
<RESULT>999</RESULT>
</GROUP>
<GROUP>
<ID>4</ID>
<RESULT>631</RESULT>
</GROUP>
</GROUPS>
```

Answer (score 0):

XSLT can certainly do that, most elegantly in XSLT 3:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="old-doc">
<GROUPS>
<GROUP>
<ID>1</ID>
<RESULT>123</RESULT>
</GROUP>
<GROUP>
<ID>2</ID>
<RESULT>999</RESULT>
</GROUP>
</GROUPS>      
  </xsl:param>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:key name="id-ref" match="GROUP[ID]/RESULT" use="../ID"/>

  <xsl:template match="GROUP[ID]/RESULT[key('id-ref', ../ID, $old-doc)]">
      <xsl:copy-of select="key('id-ref', ../ID, $old-doc)"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNmCzsx

In the example I have inlined the first XML but you can of course use `<xsl:param name="old-doc" select="doc('old.xml')"/>` instead.

Saxon-C is available from Saxonica with a Python 3 binding.